# Yii framework - multiple download

Tags: php, yii

I'm developing a database interface using the Yii framework. I have a table called *take* which stores audio files. I've added the advanced search in the index page and a link to download all the files resulting from the search, as follows:

```
<?php
/* @var $this takeController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Takes',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Create take', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Create multiple take', 'url'=>array('create_multiple')),
    array('label'=>'Manage take', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){

    $.fn.yiiListView.update('takelistview', { 

        data: $(this).serialize()
    });

    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Takes</h1>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php  $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'id'=>'takelistview',
    'sortableAttributes'=>array('id', 'data', 'take_mono_nf_id', 'take_mono_ff_id')
)); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Download all','#',array('class'=>'download-button')); ?>

<form style="display: hidden" action="index.php?r=take/download_several" method="POST" id="form">

</form>
<script>
    $('.download-button').click(function(){
        var i = 0;
        var indexes = [];   
        while($.fn.yiiListView.getKey('takelistview', i)){
            indexes[i] = $.fn.yiiListView.getKey('takelistview', i);

            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" id="indexes" name="indexes[]" value="'+indexes[i]+'"/>';
            document.getElementById('form').appendChild(newdiv);            
            i++;
        }
        newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        //newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" id="folder" name="folder" value="'+folder+'"/>';
        document.getElementById('form').appendChild(newdiv);    
        //$("#indexes").val(indexes);
        $("#form").submit();

    });

</script>
```

In the controller file, the action *download_several* creates a zip files and downloads it:

```
public function actionDownload_several(){
        $indexes = $_POST['indexes'];       
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = "files.zip"; // Zip name
        $zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);     

        foreach($indexes as $i){
            /* query to retrieve the file name starting from the index */
            $file = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../data/'.$name.'/takes/'.$filename;
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file),  file_get_contents($file)); 
            //file_put_contents($folder.$file, file_get_contents($myfile));     //provare ftp_nb_get
        }
        $zip->close();
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zip_name);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));
        readfile($zip_name);
        unlink($zip_name);
    }
```

The problem is the following. In the view page the result of the advanced search is divided into pages. When I press the "Download all" link, only the files from the current page are downloaded. **I want to download all the results**. I'm pretty shure that the problem is in `$.fn.yiiListView` but I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the function `$.fn.yiiListView.getKey()` only returns the index from the current html:

```
/**
 * Returns the key value for the specified row
 * @param id string the ID of the list view container
 * @param index integer the zero-based index of the data item
 * @return string the key value
 */
$.fn.yiiListView.getKey = function(id, index) {
        return $('#'+id+' > div.keys > span:eq('+index+')').text();
};
```

The pagination is preventing the function to get all keys because it is not loaded on the page.

To get all of the data, you need to send all the indexes with your html in your view. For example in a `js array` like this:

```
<script>    
var allIndexes = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $allIndexes).'"' ?>]; //creates js array from php array
</script>
```

The script above echos the values from the PHP array `$allIndexes` into the `js var allIndexes`

Now you need to get the indexes in the `$allIndexes` PHP array.
You can do this in your `Controller`.

For example:

```
$criteria = ... // create your criteria to only get the id's consistent with your ListView
$allIndexes = Take::model()->findAll($criteria); //if Take is your model name.
```

Now only post all the indexes from your `allIndexes js array` in the `downloadAll onclick()` function you've created and it should download everything.

Good luck!

-- edit --

Everytime you click on a "next page" the `takes` get updated to the current stance of the database.

I suggest you update your `js array` on this event, so everything is always up to date and consistent.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I didn't understand the last two lines of code. If I'm not wrong, when the index page is loaded after an advanced search I have to retrieve the search criteria and call the `findAll()` method. But how can I retrieve the criteria?

Comment: They are in the `$dataProvider` you use: [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) in your CListView widget. By the looks of your view, you are creating them in your `Controller`

Comment: Ok so just to recap: I get the criteria from `$dataProvider`, then query the models with `findAll()` and finally I call my function passing the resulting indexes. Correct? Thanks again

Comment: The use of `criteria `was a suggestion. I am assuming you have your `takes` stored in a database somewhere and showing them with the `ListView`. You want the same `takes` in your `js array` as in your `ListView`. How you get them there is up to you because I don't know what the rest of your application looks like. So you may use `findAll()` or you may not, it's up to you :)